# Rosemary room temperature at winter

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I consistently read in non-scientific resources that I have to put my rosemary to low temperature (about 10°C) in winter (unless I don't want it to freeze). I googled, but I fail to find a scientific resource about why room temperature is not good for it. Do you have any explanation (with scientific references ofc.)?

Comment: can you provide any reference to the article where you got the info?...cause your q is not too clear...like, in winter you want to keep the plant in low temperature, in order not to freeze it....it's ridiculous...

Comment: @souvikbhattacharya It doesn't freeze by 10°C, which is lower than standard room temperature 20°C. What don't you understand?

Comment: Either the rosemary is a naturally cold-weather plant and just prefers colder temperatures, or the plant needs cold weather to trigger winter behavior. Some plants need to hibernate during the cold months.

Comment: @JeremyKemball What if I don't trigger the winter behavior? Ohh actually that is the main question as well...

Comment: I have no idea. You might be able to find someone who knows a lot about rosemary on gardening.stackexchange.com ? The tree equivalent is called vernalization and can apparently out and out kill a tree. I have no idea why, but there you go.

Comment: @JeremyKemball Do you think this is off-topic and should be moved to gardening?

Comment: I mean you'd have to reword it to something more like 'what happens if I don't properly overwinter my rosemary' but this isn't entirely off-topic here. It might be unanswerable due to lack of research, but on-topic nonetheless.

Comment: @JeremyKemball I created a topic in gardening as well. The result is unconclusive yet. Some of them claims that it would survive in room temperature, some of them claims the opposite. :-) I'll try to find articles about mediterran plant hibernation meanwhile.

Comment: I did not find scientific articles in the topic. Non scientific resources claim that is is possible to overwinter rosemary at room temperature, but it is hard. It requires at least 8 hours of light, humidity, and almost, but not totally dry soil. I'll give it a try.

Comment: As a bioassay, I have for years seen rosemary growing in the median strips of highways in Downtown Las Vegas, a pretty warm place most of the time. You can Google Vegas weather data, but it has to be well over 100 F in those medians much of the year. Right next to Bellagio they had rosemary growing in the medians for years, not sure if it is still there.

Comment: @LynnGriffith I asked a botanist. According to her, it can withstand -15°C degrees, so I left it outside. It's still alive! :-)